# Why does /proc/cpuinfo list 0 cores in processor 1 on Openstack?

Tags: linux, cpu, openstack

I create a VM with Openstack Ocata. When I use the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, it shows messages:

```
processor : 0
physical id : 0
siblings : 1
core id : 0
cpu cores : 1

processor : 1
physical id : 0
siblings : 1
core id : 0
cpu cores : 0
```

Why does it show 0 for CPU cores in processor 1?

Comment: Couldn't it be related to the configuration you did and haven't included with the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've assigned one `core` and two `thread` to the virtual CPU.

`core id` starts from 0. But as two thread present in a single `core` of your configuration you're getting two entries there with same `core id` i.e. 0.